# How can I get FULL list of Startup Programs?

Tags: c#, startup

I'm trying to get full list of Startup Programs:

```
ManagementClass cls = new ManagementClass(new ManagementPath("Win32_StartupCommand"));
ManagementObjectCollection coll = cls.GetInstances();
```

> But 32bit registry was not processed
>   \Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run  
> And
>   switched off startups also ...\Run\not active

How can I get the complete list?

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: @ibo its the last line of the question.  its also in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go through the registry key:
User Level:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Machine Level:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```